# Load a layout in my custom plugin storefront page

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I have a custom plugin built for Shopware 6. I created a new route `/certificate` with a `certificate.html.twig` view to show a list of the custom entity along with other html contents.

I want to be able to edit the HTML contents of this page (not the list) from the administration area, so I went to 'Content' > 'Shopping Experience' and created a custom layout.

I inserted my HTML tags as text type (in the source code interface).

**The problem:** I want to link this created layout with the custom twig template I created (or any other approach to make this HTML content editable from the administration).

How to load the layout in my controller at least?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller you fetch the `cms_page` entity with the id of your shopping experience layout. You then pass it to your template

```php
$criteria = new Criteria([$cmsPageId]);
$criteria->addAssociation('sections.blocks');

$cmsPage = $this->container->get('cms_page.repository')->search($criteria, $context)->first();

return $this->renderStorefront('@MyPlugin/storefront/page/certificate/certificate.html.twig', ['cmsPage' => $cmsPage]);
```

In your custom template you can then include the template for rendering the shopping experience.

```html
{% set cmsPageClasses = ('cms-page ' ~ cmsPage.cssClass|striptags)|trim %}
<div class="{{ cmsPageClasses }}">
    {% sw_include "@Storefront/storefront/page/content/detail.html.twig" with {'cmsPage': cmsPage} %}
</div>
```

Comment: I made the same solution before you post the answer, but I will make it an accepted answer.